# Power BI not loading tables

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I imported some collections from mongo DB into power bi. When I close and apply from power query into power bi, I keep getting this error :

Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 1.4(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.12 mongosqld v2.14.4]This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet. The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed. OLE DB or ODBC error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E4E. OLE DB or ODBC error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E4E. OLE DB or ODBC error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E4E. OLE DB or ODBC error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E4E. '.

Answer (score 0):

You create a data model in power BI and after update data, you need to check if table's primary key is unique. If it is duplicated, you can get this error.

If that is not a solution for you, check it out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/get-data/9-import-errors

[image]